# show all markerviews at once with MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I would like to have all of my markers visible at once (eg weather graph, with icons).

I came up with this, but maybe someone knows a better solution?

```
public class MyChart extends LineChart {

    //...constructors

    public void drawAllMarkers() {
        List<Highlight> all = new ArrayList<Highlight>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mData.getXValCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mData.getDataSetCount(); j++) {
                all.add(new Highlight(i, j));
            }
        }
        highlightValues(all.toArray(new Highlight[all.size()]));
        drawMarkers();
    }
}
```

With this solution, I still have to mess around with click events, and check what other functionality this breaks.

```
 chart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //consume all touches
            return true;
        }
    });
```